# Unique constraint violation found - Unable to save new cookie on bin/magento s:up

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4, setup-upgrade, docker, unique-constraint

I just recently switched over to mac for work and am working on getting my local environment set up. Everything's been going much more smoothly than on my PC with Virtualbox, but when I go running `bin/magento setup:upgrade` for the first time I get the following error:

```
Installing data... Unable to save new cookie. Error: Unique constraint violation found
```

[image: Installing data... Unable to save new cookie. Error: Unique constraint violation found]

This is the result of going to magento2.docker/

[image: Unable to run setup:upgrade]

I'm running the `enterprise cloud 2.3.4 on docker`. It seems that this might possibly be the result of duplicate tables. I'm using the exact same DB as I previously was on Ubuntu so unless something corrupted during the transfer I don't see why it would be an issue with the DB dump. I haven't run into this error before and unfortunately haven't found an exact example with the same context as mine, although I'm sure someone here must have an idea. Thanks!

UPDATE (08/03/20):

Running `DELETE FROM amasty_gdprcookie_cookie WHERE 1;` running `bin/magento setup:db-upgrade -vvv` to check for errors, then re-running `bin/magento setup:upgrade` did the trick. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: I'd checked permissions with your system that session can be created.. it may be not really only magento issue

Comment: I just double checked my permissions and while inside docker, everything is root which is correct. Anything more specific I should look for?

Comment: I have not used docker in a while but for what I have used either docker or vagrant, the problem of permissions was often happening. I'd verify a basic php page can create session to get yourself confident. Usually, we'd want the webserver owner to create the session and therefore should session folder not belong to the webserver owner?

Comment: Looks like the permissions are ok at this point, I'm able to pull up the nginx page and pretty much the error remains that the schema needs to be updated. I've updated my post with a screenshot of what happens when I try going to magento2.docker/. Still haven't found out what exactly is preventing me from running ```bin/magento setup:upgrade``, but once I do I'll update this post. To anyone else reading this, any further input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I managed to debug this and I found that the module does not check if the cookies table already has data before inserting the initial cookies.

This happens when you run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` after you imported a database dump.
The solution was to empty the `amasty_gdprcookie_cookie` table and run again the command.

Have a nice day

Comment: I had a feeling it was something along those lines. My lazy workaround was to just disable my amasty_gdpr for the meantime since this is just for local dev, but your solution sounds much more complete. I'll try this and update with my results shortly. Thanks!

Comment: Just as an update, I tried clearing the table and re-running the setup:upgrade command, and for some reason I'm running into the same issue with the same exact error message. Is there a step that I'm missing maybe?

Comment: Hi,
The steps I made were:
 - Run `php bin/magento setup:db-data:upgrade` to see the actual error
 - This way I saw that the Item that initial setup was trying to insert was already in the `amasty_gdprcookie_cookie` table.
 - I ran `DELETE FROM amasty_gdprcookie_cookie WHERE 1;`
 - Then I ran the setup command again; and it worked.

Comment: Or maybe `TRUNCATE TABLE amasty_gdprcookie_cookie;` is more suitable...

Comment: Awesome, it works! Since I already cleared the table manually last time, `TRUNCATE TABLE` didn't work, but `DELETE FROM amasty_gdprcookie_cookie WHERE 1;` did the trick. I'll update my post with the working solution. Thanks again